# my aplication has stopped before start activity

Tags: android, android-emulator

> my code here

```
    /**
```

> ```
>     * GLExample java
>      */
> ```

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    /**
     * @author pream
     *
     */
    public class GLExample extends Activity{



    GLSurfaceView oursurface;

     /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        oursurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        oursurface.setRenderer(new GLRendererEx());

        setContentView(oursurface);
    }



    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onPause()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();

        oursurface.onPause();
    }




    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onResume()
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        oursurface.onResume();
    }



    }

  **
```

> GLRendererEX***/

```
    package net.sourceforge.users.shafiul;

    import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
    import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

    import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
    import android.opengl.GLU;


    public class GLRendererEx implements Renderer {


    private GLTriangleEx tri;



    public void GLRendererEx() {

        tri = new GLTriangleEx();



    }


    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);        //boosting performances
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);

        gl.glClearColor(.8f, 0f, .2f, 1f);//red,green&blue,alpha for transparency

        gl.glClearDepthf(1f);

        //gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);//masking.handling colour buffer 
        //camera to look into

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
        //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);
        //GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -30, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);

        tri.draw(gl);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        //viewport settings

        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

        float ratio = (float) width/height;

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 25);              

    }


}

/**
```

*

> GLTraingle.java

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

/**
 * @author pream
 *
 */
public class GLTriangleEx {

    private float vertices[]={

            0f , 1f ,  //p0
            1f ,-1f,    //p2
            -1f,-1f //p3
    };

    private FloatBuffer vertBuff;
    private short[] pIndex = {0,1,2};

    private ShortBuffer pBuff;

    public GLTriangleEx()
{
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);//how much 
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        vertBuff =bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        vertBuff.put(vertices);
        vertBuff.position(0);


        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(pIndex.length*2);

        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

        pBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        pBuff.put(pIndex);
        pBuff.position(0);

}


    public void draw(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW); //clockwise
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);//size-2d object,type,stride,buffr pointer.

        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, pIndex.length,GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, pBuff);// mode,count,type,indices
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);


    }
}
```

> this is my logcat ..please help me...

```
   11-28 13:56:22.209: D/dalvikvm(855): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 42K, 4% free 2549K/2640K, paused 74ms, total 78ms
11-28 13:56:22.219: I/dalvikvm-heap(855): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.451MB for 960016-byte allocation
11-28 13:56:22.309: D/dalvikvm(855): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 3% free 3486K/3580K, paused 85ms, total 85ms
11-28 13:56:23.049: D/gralloc_goldfish(855): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
11-28 13:56:50.079: D/dalvikvm(855): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 943K, 25% free 3021K/4028K, paused 97ms, total 108ms
11-28 13:56:50.369: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:56:50.619: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 149 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:56:50.909: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 63 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:56:51.169: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:56:51.649: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:56:51.819: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:56:51.919: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:07.889: D/dalvikvm(855): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 13% free 3506K/4028K, paused 149ms, total 168ms
11-28 13:57:08.059: D/dalvikvm(855): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 444K, 15% free 3463K/4028K, paused 98ms, total 99ms
11-28 13:57:08.099: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 298 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:08.905: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 43 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:08.999: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:09.338: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:09.479: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:09.599: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:09.689: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:10.119: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:10.209: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:10.289: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:11.139: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 100 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:11.159: D/libEGL(855): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
11-28 13:57:11.239: D/libEGL(855): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
11-28 13:57:11.639: W/dalvikvm(855): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
11-28 13:57:11.639: E/AndroidRuntime(855): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 82
11-28 13:57:11.639: E/AndroidRuntime(855): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 13:57:11.639: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at net.sourceforge.users.shafiul.GLRendererEx.onDrawFrame(GLRendererEx.java:54)
11-28 13:57:11.639: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1523)
11-28 13:57:11.639: E/AndroidRuntime(855):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
11-28 13:57:13.439: I/Choreographer(855): Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-28 13:57:16.929: I/Process(855): Sending signal. PID: 855 SIG: 9
```

Comment: post your full stacktrace.

Comment: Null Pointe Exception - Line 54. I can't help until you tell me which is line 54 in the above code as YOU CANNOT SEE LINES HERE AS YOU DO IN ECLIPSE

Comment: please help i am new here , @Rahul Gupta

Comment: Dude, when you get a null pointer exception, start reading the log cat. cause by Null Pointer Exception at so and so. Start double clicking the error lines. It will take directly to the line which is null. Tell me that line. Don't tell me the number, just the code at that line which in your case is line 54.

Answer (score 1):

Your `tri` object seems to be null when you call the `.draw()` method on it in the onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) method. Not much other possibilities, that could give you a null in that line.

I don't know what your app is supposed to do but remove the `void` from the constructor of the GLRendererEx class. Constructors cannot return `void`.

This is how your constructor is supposed to look like:

```
public GLRendererEx() {

    tri = new GLTriangleEx();

}
```

The void keyword essentially blocked your constructor to be called, because it was not recognized as a constructor. *Constructors don't have an explicit return type* (so no `void` or whatever).

Comment: sorry  any suggestion ,, please

Comment: Remove the 'void' from  the constructor of GLRendererEx. I'll edit my comment and add the correct constructor.

Comment: already correct it sorry for inconvenience..working..thanks..keep on good work